# Mockito works fines when using anystring() and not when values are used set to an object in @setup method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

```
@InjectMocks
```

for the class that contains jdbc call.

```
@Mock
```

jdbc template

@Mock 
private DataAccessException dataAccessException;

works fine:

```
when(jdbcTemplate.update(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenThrow(dataAccessException);
```

Did not work:

```
 when(jdbcTemplate.update("revoke", "1", "1", "JA122")).thenThrow(dataAccessException);
```

I am new to testing and Mockito. Can any one explain why this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are mocking a Spring JDBC [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html), the [`update`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method receives a vararg, which you are calling with four strings. In the second example, your second and third arguments are `int` literals, so the arguments aren't matched, and thus you execution does not match the mocked expectation. Just turn them to string literals and you should be fine:

```
when(jdbcTemplate.update("revoke", "1", "1", "JA122")).
    thenThrow(dataAccessException);`
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Please look at the changes. Even changing as per you comments didn't work.